# I receive an error with pdo statement on a tutorial I am working on

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is from a tutorial I am going through. So I can better understand PDO with prepared statements. I don't want to continue until I find out why I am getting this error. I double checked the code and I don't see any syntax error or has this code change and is outdated.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EjPUJ5QLSY&list=PLyKBLKYqadGmD33SGjyk_MXrGAHVTVcqa

> Call to undefined method PDOStatement::excecute() in C:\wamp\www\youtube\connect.php on line 18

My code is:

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "youtube";

$user = "root";
$password="";

$david = "David Thorn";
$user_id =0;
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=$host" , $user , $password);

if( $pdo )
        {
        $smt = $pdo->prepare("select * from users where user_id>:user_id");
        $smt->bindParam(":Name", $user_id );

        if( $smt->excecute())
        {
        $rows = $smt->fetchAll();
        print_r($rows);
        }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to change `excecute` to `execute`. That's all! (Typo).

Comment: You prepare for `:user_id` and bind to `:Name`.

Comment: `$smt->bindParam(":Name", $user_id );` you may also change to `$smt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id );`

Comment: I just saw that was trying to edit my comment sorry. I am marking this answered as soon as I can it says wait 5min